# How to Archive List in Share Point 2003 (WSS 2.0)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am beginner on Share Point and now I am tasked to archive Share Point 2003 (WSS 2.0). My plan is to export out the list to be kept as archive and delete those list before 2014. How can I achieve it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
Richmond